# GWT 2.4 customized ListBox doesn't fire Change event

Tags: gwt, listbox

I have added some extra functionality to the standard GWT ListBox by extending it like so:

```
public class FeatureListBox extends ListBox
{
    public FeatureListBox()
    {
    }
    public FeatureListBox(boolean isMultipleSelect)
    {
        super(isMultipleSelect);
    }
    public FeatureListBox(Element element)
    {
        super(element);
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy here. However, the Change event is not firing now, or at least the handler (attached per below) is not getting invoked.

```
FeatureListBox listBox = new FeatureListBox();
listBox.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler()
{
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event)
    {
        // Do something here...
    }
});
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the no-argument constructor from `FeatureListBox` or call `super()` inside it, otherwise the initialization in the superclasses won't happen, which would probably result in what you're seeing.

Comment: Borya, thanks, I actually noticed it myself but that wasn't the solution. I am going to update my post with the details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the way I was using my custom list box. In my application I wrap GWT Widgets around existing DOM elements on the page using the static **wrap()** methods of their widget classes in which the widgets get marked as attached, making them fire events. I didn't do that with my custom list box class originally, so I ended up implementing a static **wrap()** method similar to the one of the regular ListBox widget and using it in my code. Everything works like a charm now.